# Simultaneously scale and translate ImageView based on Target

Tags: android, android-animation

What I want to do is simultaneously scale and translate an ImageView based when the user touches is. The final position and size of the ImageView should be equal to the target.

Below is a snipper of the OnClickListener attached to every ImageView that should perform this action. The new position and size is obtained from ivYou, which also is an ImageView.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create animations
        int[] from = new int[2];
        int[] to = new int[2];
        //v.getLocationInWindow(from);
        v.getLocationOnScreen(from);
        //ivYou.getLocationInWindow(to);
        ivYou.getLocationOnScreen(to);
        TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, to[0] - from[0], 0, to[1] - from[0]);

        float factorX = ivYou.getWidth() / v.getWidth();
        float factorY = ivYou.getHeight() / v.getHeight();
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, factorX, 1.0f, factorY);

        // Create animation set
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        set.setFillAfter(true);
        set.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
        set.addAnimation(transAnim);
        set.addAnimation(scaleAnim);

        // Start animations and disable click listener
        v.startAnimation(set);
        v.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
```

ANIM_DURATION is 2000 miliseconds.

When I run this code the strangest things happen. The ImageView turns half a circle and gets smaller then its supposed to be. When I do not add the ScaleAnimator to the animation set, then the ImageView is moved to the new position. However, this new position isn't the same for every ImageView. Note that the ImageView's with this OnClickListener all have a different initial position.

Any help and feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to have pivot of the scale-animation in the center of the imageview. And then you have to include the offset (due to scale) in your calculation for the translate animation. I don't have working code for that, you have to think about it yourself :|

Comment: Added "ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f" to ScaleAnimation. No luck with that.

Comment: Yes, and what's the problem now? That the translate animation is not working properly?

Comment: No visible changes after I added the pivot point.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue, where doing a scale animation at the same time as a translate animation results in the view taking a curved path with a different ending point for the translation.  Can't seem to find any answers for this on SO!

Comment: If I remember correctly my solution was to not do it simultaneously because of limited development time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this animation by wrapping the target View in a layout group and animating them separately.

In other words, I translate the wrapper layout, and scale the child view.  Translating and scaling the same view at the same time always seems to result in unexpected animation trajectories as the scaling messes with the coordinate system the translate animation is using.

```
translateTarget.animate().x(deltaX).y(deltaY).setDuration(1000);
scaleTarget.animate().scaleX(0.01f).scaleY(0.01f).setDuration(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this constructor? 
ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, float pivotX, float pivotY)  and have pivotX be widthofimageview/2 and pivotY be the heightofimageview/2 for it to be the center. This is what I used in my translate scale animation.